# Angular.js Dynamic routing with templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, angular-ui-router

I have a web site where the code is organised in 3 folders: websiteTemplate-Front with angular.js- Back witn node.js.
I need to create a dynamic routing when the user when he click on the logo picture in the front  the user will be redirected to the index.html in the

> /websiteTemplate/src/fr/index.html

In javascript File.js

$scope.goToWelcomePage = function ()
    {

```
    var loggedUser = UserService.getLoggedInUser();
    if (loggedUser)
    {
        if(loggedUser.hasPromo && "number" === typeof loggedUser.promoOfferId
        && ("/user/account" !== $location.$$path && "/user/invoices" !== $location.$$path ))
        {
            $uibModal.open(
                {
                    templateUrl: "../../views/dialog/confirmation.html",
                    controller: "DialogConfirmationController",
                    size: "lg",
                    resolve: {
                        dialogTitle: function ()
                        {
                            return $scope.i18n.user.summary.confirmation.title;
                        },
                        dialogContent: function ()
                        {
                            return $scope.i18n.user.summary.confirmation.message;
                        },
                        dialogOnConfirm: function ()
                        {
                            return function ()
                            {
                                var webSiteUrl = $rootScope.getWebSiteUrl();
                                window.location = webSiteUrl;
                            };
                        },
                        dialogOnCancel: function ()
                        {
                            return function ()
                            {
                            };
                        },
                    }
                });
        }
        else
        {
            $location.path("");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $location.path("login");
    }
};
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: How can I create a Dynamic routing when the new user click on the logo, He should be redirected to the /websitetemplate/src/fr/index.html using goToWelcome()?

Comment: I tried but not working:if (!loggedUser)
  {
   /*$location.path("login");*/

   templateUrl: "../yemp-website/src/fr/index.html"
  }
  else
  {
   if (loggedUser.hasPromo && "number" === typeof loggedUser.promoOfferId
    && ("/user/account" !== $location.$$path && "/user/invoices" !== $location.$$path ))
   {